# How do I get people to like me after going on a rampage?

Tags: watch-dogs

I want to play Watch Dogs as the "good Aiden" but sometimes I just drive rather poorly, causing me to kill civilians, or I end up shooting civilians on accident.

Now I wanted to know how I can actually increase my reputation within the city. The only thing I know about is stopping crimes but are there some other ways?

Comment: save citizens from crimes.

Comment: that's what he said he knows.

Comment: @RandomDisplayName - Just because they already know the only method that can be repeatable does not make my comment less correct.

Comment: no only redundant ;)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Some of the storyline missions give you a reputation bonus for completing them with minimal bloodshed. But considering that these aren't repeatable, they are not a sustainable way to fix your reputation.

The best way to do so is to prevent crimes. Note that you get a greater reputation bonus for both taking down the criminals before they hurt the victims (but not before the "Crime propability" bar turns red and the "Suggestion: Intervene" HUD message appears - you won't get any reputation bonus when you scare away the criminal too early) and for performing a melee takedown on the criminal instead of just killing them. There are three different ways to notice crimes:

- Remote profiling crime reports you get automatically while being in an area with unlocked ctOS connectivity
- When you profile pedestrians you will sometimes find people with a "potential crime in progress" description. Scanning these people will also trigger a crime report.
- Sometimes people will perform spontaneous roberies on the street. You notice this by an enemy-icon suddenly appearing on the minimap

You are more likely to find the latter two in areas with a high density of moving pedestrians, like parks or the promenades near the water. The pedestrian-density seems to be higher during the day than at night. Also keep in mind that none of these events happen when you are currently on a mission.

Comment: For the spontaneuos robberies... don't shoot the guy, you'll lose rep.

Comment: As I recall you gain a fair bit of reputation when you complete the main campaign.

Answer (score 11):

In addition to stopping crimes, your reputation also increases when you rescue civilians from their cars after an accident. Sometimes, they will get stuck in their cars and you can perform a rescue action by pressing triangle on Playstation or Y on Xbox controllers, when you get close to the car's door.

Comment: Can you deliberately cause accidents, then rescue them?

Comment: @Bobson you can

Comment: You can also rescue them from cars during a shoot-out.

Answer (score 3):

Well, there are several methods to gain good reputation.

- The first and  most common method is getting a crime alert, going to the area the criminal is in and stopping him or her.
- The second method  is not so common, however. This method is quite like the last except there is no alert for these crimes and these crimes consists of murder and thievery.
- The third method is uncommon and is called a " ctOS alert ". Quite like the first method, this can have several crimes bunched up into one alert.
- The fourth method is most common in a " Criminal convoy ". When hiding behind a car that is damaged there is a chance that the original driver is stuck in the car. You can press triangle on the PS4 near the door and force the NPC driver out of the car.
- The last method that I know of is the following: Some missions give good reputation. You have to complete the mission beforehand though.

Comment: EDIT: You also gain reputation via completing the main campaign.

Comment: can you find a video of a ctOS alert? I'm not familiar with those, don't recall having one occur.

Answer (score 0):

I will lead on one guy in a gun fight. Keep walking back and keep his attention. Then rescue everyone that needs help. You can keep this going for a long time and go from lowest to highest rep in about 5 minutes.

Answer (score -1):

To not get as bad rep.

- Stop commiting crimes
- Help pedestrians
- Escort pedestrians out of vehicles and escort out
- Prevent convoys

ALL that. Kill Bill tactics.